# Error reading character of string

Tags: visual-c++

I have read many questions on this error .However, i cannot find the codes similar to mine.

[This is he code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnJXA.png)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question?

For one thing, the code won't work. The first `for` loop should go from 0 to n, not from 0 to 2.